# How to avoid big shared data being cached to files in python multiprocessing on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, memory, swig, python-multiprocessing

I have a big data set of about 10G to analyze by python3 multiprocessing. The data is put in a shared array:

```
SharedArray = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, l*n)
inputs = np.ctypeslib.as_array(SharedArray.get_obj()).reshape((l, n))
for j in range(n):
    inputs[:, j] =np.float64(struct.unpack_from('%sd'%l, f.read(lz)))
```

Then I created a Pool of 4 sub-processes. Each process pass the `inputs` into a function written in C++ and glued by swig as in-place array according to numpy.i documentation so that numpy would not try to make a copy of it:

```
%apply (double * INPLACE_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2){
    (double * inputs, int nrow, int ncol)
};
```

However, `inputs` is read-only and I never assigned values to it.

Everything is working fine, except that Mac OS X seems to have very strange memory managements. It appears that every sub-process has a ~10G of memory on Activity Monitor, but the total memory used is <18G. The math simply does not add up ([Mac OS X memory used screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJHl.png)). The memory are indeed shared, otherwise there would not be enough memory and the system would freeze every program. However, multiprocessing and Mac OS X failed to communicate about the shared memory.

More annoyingly, Activity Monitor showed that only ~6G of my total 16G RAM had been used and most memories had been written into "Cached Files" and Swap. As a result, each process could only use 50% of CPU of a single core (4 cores in total), which is a waste of processing power. Mac OS X typically use cached files and swap only when the Physical Memory (RAM) is almost fully used (Memory Used should be close to 14G) for normal programs.

So, is there a way to resolve this problem, either by multiprocessing side or by Mac OS X side? Thanks!